# How to access PostgreSQL pg_log folder without being the postgres user and running into permission issues?

Tags: macos, postgresql

On my mac os x development machine,  I have postgres 9.1 installed to `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1` and the data directory for PostgreSQL is in `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/data` I have configured logging so I get good logs out of postgres about what sql queries are executing on the server .... etc such that these are written to `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/data/pg_log` I am using the enterprise db pre packaged postgres binary.

The problem is that $PGDATA is owned by the postgres user which is running the postgres processes. When I changed the permissions on the data directory with `chmod o+xr data` postgres refused to start and tells me that it can not start with the postgres directory having permissions to anything but the postgres user.

```
FATAL:  data directory "/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/data" has group or world access
DETAIL:  Permissions should be u=rwx (0700)
```

Having to sudo in and out of the postgres dir just to get at the log files is annoying.

What is a good way to configure postgres logging on Mac OS X so that it is easy to access the log files from any user that is logged in, rather than having to use sudo or be the postgres user?

**UPDATE** See my answer below, for the exact recipe I used to make it work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The simple fact is that PostgreSQL won't let you do this.  However, there is a better solution, which is to make sure the following are set in the postgresql.conf:

This one is the default.  If it is commented out and not otherwise set, that's ok:

```
log_destination = 'stderr'
```

This needs to be set on:

```
logging_collector = on
```

You can then point this somewhere else:

```
log_directory = 'pg_log'
```

You could point this somewhere you can access it.  For example, give postgres appropriate access and point to:

```
log_directory = '/var/log/postgresql'
```

Then as long as it isn't in the data directory you can set whatever permissions you want.

Comment: I followed your solution, and it works very well, except that each new log file created belongs to the postgres user, and is not readable unless you use postgres or root users. Any solution to make sure any newly created log file is accessible to all?

Comment: Okay, found it, it is via the log_file_mode parameter in postgresql.conf.

Answer (score 8):

Steps I used to make it work.

- Create a directory `/var/pg_log` and make it world readable and writable `chmod o+wxr`
- Set the following values in postgresql.conf file

  log_directory = '/var/pg_log'

  log_file_mode = 0506
- restart postgres
- `/var/pg_log` should have postgres .log files that you can monitor with the mac os x, console utility. no sudo required to see what is going on in there.

Note Postgres refused to allow any permission above 511 on the log file.

Comment: Do you mean that Postgres would not allow group/other writable?